# Error PHP to Update Mysql Row

Tags: php, mysql

what wrong with my PHP MySQL Update ? 
this my php code :

```
<?
if(isset($_POST['update_judulanime'])){
$jdl_nime = trim($_POST['JDLAN']);
$setID = $_GET['nime_id'];
$queryUPJDL = "UPDATE `anime_completed` SET `judul_anime` = '$jdl_nime' WHERE `anime_completed`.`nime_id` = '".$setID."'";
$exUPJDL = mysql_query($queryUPJDL);
if($exUPJDL){
   echo "Success update Judul Anime";
}else{
   echo "Error Update".mysql_error();
}
?>
```

if i push this button, it doesn't execute that query
this my html button code :

```
<button type="submit" name="update_judulanime">Update Title</button>
```

it just loading but doesn't update the row.. no error reports

Comment: is it going into the error block ? if yes...then what is the exact error message

Comment: Error........????

Comment: Rohitas Behera what do you mean?

Comment: $_POST and $_GET, both? Something is wrong there..

Comment: echo the variable $queryUPJDL  and post what it prints here. Ideally that query needs  to work on mysql.

Comment: @UmashankarDas i've just copy the sql query from mysql and nothing changes.. query not executed..

Comment: is your php code executing or not? If not, then check your html.

Comment: The curly parenthesis at the end of `if(isset($_POST['update_judulanime'])){
` is never closed. Please fix that and follow @UmashankarDas 's advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. !!

```
    <?
    if(isset($_POST['update_judulanime'])){
    $jdl_nime = trim($_POST['JDLAN']);
    $setID = $_GET['nime_id'];
    $queryUPJDL = "UPDATE `anime_completed` SET `judul_anime` = '$jdl_nime' WHERE `anime_completed`.`nime_id` = '".$setID."'";
    $exUPJDL = mysql_query($queryUPJDL);
    if($exUPJDL){
       echo "Success update Judul Anime";
    }else{
       echo "Error Update".mysql_error();
    }
}
    ?>
```

You Haven't Closed `if(isset($_POST['update_judulanime'])) {` braces. So it will be showing empty screen or no errors.

Hope this helps.